# File in the same folder but still get FileNotFoud

Tags: python, file, visual-studio-code, pickle

I am trying to open a .dat file by Pickle. Although the file is at the same folder as my .py file, when I run I get a FileNotFoundError.
(FYI: I am using VScode to run the file, however, it runs perfectly fine when I use Terminal)

here is my code

```
import pickle

websites_list = pickle.load(open("websites.dat","rb"))
print(websites_list)
```

This is the .py path:

```
/Users/lequangdang/Documents/WSC/WSC_2.0/changewebsiteGUI.py
```

here is the .dat path: `/Users/lequangdang/Documents/WSC/WSC_2.0/websites.dat`

Here is the error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'websites.dat'
```

Comment: Try ```open("/Users/lequangdang/Documents/WSC/WSC_2.0/websites.dat","rb")``` instead.

Comment: Oh that worked, thanks a lot

Comment: Vs Code has the concept for work directory. The relative path is base on work directory.

Answer (score 2):

The relative path is base on work directory when using vscode, but is base on py file itself when using terminal.

For example the directory structure seems like:

`WSC---WSC2.0---changewebsiteGUI.py`

when you open WSC in vscode, `pickle.load(open("websites.dat","rb"))` will call the path `WSC/websites.dat` and that's why you have `FileNotFoundError`

one way to solve this is to set the vscode `launch.json`, add this line:

```
"cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/WSC2.0"
```

the other way is to use some function to get the abs path of pyfile itself:

```
os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

Comment: oh my god finally I get a clear explanation, thanks a lot, you made my day